# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token "=", expecting "," or ";" in D:\ROMINA\Downloads\XAMPP_\htdocs\LeilaRamirez3roC\resultados.php on line 79

Tags: php, mysql

Llevo 6 hrs tratando de solucionar este error:  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token "=", expecting "," or ";" in D:\ROMINA\Downloads\XAMPP_\htdocs\LeilaRamirez3roC\resultados.php on line 79.
No se a que se debe he revisado un monton de veces la linea y no creo que este mal esta es la linea 79: `echo '<a href= "index.php"> Ingresar nuevo usuario</a>';`

```html
<?php

$comidas = "";
$calorias = 0;
$observacion = "";

$cedula = $_POST['cedula'];
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$edad = $_POST['edad'];
$sexo = $_POST['sexo'];
$direccion = $_POST['direccion'];

if(!empty($_POST['resultado'])){
    foreach($_POST['resultado'] as $seleccionado){

        $comidas .= $seleccionado .", ";
        $calorias = $calorias+300;

    }
}


if($calorias >= 200 && $calorias <=300){

    $observacion = "La cantidad de calorias a consumir es moderada";

}
elseif($calorias < 200){

    $observacion = "La cantidad de calorias a consumir no es suficiente";

}

elseif($calorias > 300){

    $observacion = "La cantidad de calorias a consumir no es suficiente";

}

include("conexion.php");

$conexion->query("INSERT INTO $tabla (cedula,nombres_apellidos,edad,sexo,direccion,comidas,calorias,observacion) values ('$cedula','$nombre','$edad','$sexo','$direccion','$comidas','$calorias','$observacion')");

        //$consulta = "SELECT * FROM tabla where id ='2'"; si queremos que nos muestre solo un registro en especifico de ID
        $consulta = "SELECT * FROM resultados "; //nombre de la tabla a consultar

$result = mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);
if(!$result)
{
    echo "No se ha podido realizar la consulta";
}       
echo "<center><h1>REGISTRO DE USUARIOS</h1></center>";
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th><h5>CEDULA</th></h5>";
echo "<th><h5>NOMBRES y APELLIDOS</th></h5>";
echo "<th><h5>EDAD</th></h5>";
echo "<th><h5>SEXO</th></h5>";
echo "<th><h5>DIRECCIÓN</th></h5>";
echo "<th><h5>COMIDAS</th></h5>";
echo "<th><h5>CALORIAS</th></h5>";
echo "<th><h5>OBSERVACION</th></h5>";
echo "</tr>";
while ($colum = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><h6>" . $colum['cedula']. "</td></h6>";
echo "<td><h6>" . $colum['nombres_apellidos']. "</td></h6>";
echo "<td><h6>" . $colum['Comidas']. "</td></h6>"; 
echo "<td><h6>" . $colum['Sexo']. "</td></h6>";
echo "<td><h6>" . $colum['Direccion']. "</td></h6>";
echo "<td><h6>" . $colum['Comidas']. "</td></h6>"; 
echo "<td><h6>" . $colum['calorias']. "</td></h6>";
echo "<td><h6>" . $colum['observacion']. "</td></h6>"; 
echo "</tr>"; 
}   
echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($conexion);
 
echo '<a href= "index.php"> Ingresar nuevo usuario</a>';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale-1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet"
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <title>consulta db</title>
    <style>
table {
   font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   border-collapse: collapse;
     width: 100%;
}
table td, table th {
   border: 1px solid #ddd;
   padding: 8px;
}
table tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2;}
table tr:hover {background-color: #ddd;}
table th{
   padding-top: 12px;
   padding-bottom: 12px;
   text-align: left;
   background-color: #04AA6D;
   color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Has probado a cambiar las comillas simples por dobles y viceversa y eliminar el espacio en blanco despues del =?

Comment: ¿Puedes colocar el contenido de tu archivo 'conexion.php'? (oculta o cambia los valores de usuario y clave). Ya que todo en tu archivo parece estar bien, probablemente el error provenga de otra parte (por ejemplo, tienes un 'INSERT INTO $tabla' pero la variable $tabla no se ve definida en ninguna parte)